# Kendo DropDownList in row Kendo Grid filter

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I am trying to change the default behavior of a standard string filter to be a combobox (dropdownlist).

I am having some issues when I use a displayed name different from the wanted value.

For example:

I have i18n in my application, so each item inside the combo should be displayed in the correct language, still the value that a specific label refers has to remain the same.

This is what you normally whould expect.

The problem is that I cannot do that.

this is the code of my gridOptions:

```
public gridOptions() {
    return {
        scrollable: false,
        selectable: 'row',
        schema: {
            model: { id: 'id' }
        },
        filterable: {
            messages: {
                isFalse: 'Is false',
                isTrue: 'Is True'
            }
        },
        columns: [{
                field: 'name',
                title: '{{\'name\' | translate }}'
            },
            {
                field: 'combo',
                title: '{{\'combo\' | translate }}',
                filterable: {
                    extra: false,
                    operators: {
                        string: {
                            eq: 'Is Equals to'
                        }
                    },
                    ui: (e) => { this.filter(e) },
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        template: (c) => { this.filterRow(c) },
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

That uses two functions that create the dropdownlist:

```
private filter(element) {
    this.myService.getData().then( data => {
        element.kendoDropDownList(
            {
                dataTextField: 'displayName',
                dataValueField: 'name',
                dataSource: data,
                optionLabel: '--select a value--'
            }
        };
    });
}

private filterRow(container) {
    this.filter(container.element);
}
```

What I expect is that the filter shows the translated fields (for example: Green Color when the name is 'green') and that the value of 'name' property is used to filter.

Instead when I select something in the combobox the selection is not and everything is hidden by the filter.

What is strange is that if I use the field 'name' as dataTextField and any other field as dataValueField (I used 'isworkingfornoreason' as field !! ) everything works. The filter works, but the combobox elements obviously are the default string, not translated.

Can you help me figure out what is happening?

Comment: Try using `template` to render the list options. Sometimes `dataTextField` is buggy. Can you show what `data` is inside your `getData().then()` promise ?

Comment: it's an array of objects with various properties, one of them is displayName the other is 'name'